# Ignore namespaces on xmldocument in nokogiri

Tags: ruby

Im trying to learn to parse xml with nokogiri.
I dont have control of how the xml file is generated and it seems the namespaces are causing issues because they are not defined.
Im using the following test code to try to get this to work.

```
 require 'nokogiri'
 def getxml
    xml_str = <<EOF
    <root>
      <THING1:things type="Container">
        <PART1:Id type="Property">1234</PART1:Id>
        <PART1:Name type="Property">The Name1</PART1:Name>
      </THING1:things>
      <THING2:things type="Container">
        <PART2:Id type="Property">2234</PART2:Id>
        <PART2:Name type="Property">The Name2</PART2:Name>
      </THING2:things>
    </root>
EOF
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)
    puts(doc.errors())
    doc.xpath('//Id').each do |thing|
      puts(thing.inspect)
      #puts "ID   = " + thing.at_xpath('Id').content
      #puts "Name = " + thing.at_xpath('Name').content

    end
 end

getxml()
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
2:38: ERROR: Namespace prefix THING1 on things is not defined
3:34: ERROR: Namespace prefix PART1 on Id is not defined
4:36: ERROR: Namespace prefix PART1 on Name is not defined
6:38: ERROR: Namespace prefix THING2 on things is not defined
7:34: ERROR: Namespace prefix PART2 on Id is not defined
8:36: ERROR: Namespace prefix PART2 on Name is not defined
```

How am I suppose to deal with namespaces not defined.  Is there a way to ignore namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri does have the [`remove_namespaces!` method](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#but-im-lazy-and-dont-want-to-deal-with-namespaces), but it wont help in your case as your XML isn’t actually using namespaces.

As there are no namespace declarations, your XML elements are just treated as non-namespaced elements that contain a `:` character in their name. This makes it difficult to use with XPath as XPath assumes a `:` indicates a namespace.

One way to get round this is to use the [`local-name()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name) to select elements. For example to select all elements named `PART1:Id` you could use this:

```
doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="PART1:Id"]')
```

If you want to select all elements where the final part is `Id`, regardless of what the prefix is, such as `PART1:Id` and `PART2:Id`, you could combine `local-name()` with [`substring-after()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-after):

```
doc.xpath('//*[substring-after(local-name(), ":")="Id"]')
```